# RegEx Search Pattern for ASP controls with a specific element

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, visual-studio, search

I am currently trying to figure out a RegEx pattern to find certain ASP controls in the entirety of my visual studio solution. For example, I would like to find all the  controls that have a CssClass element defined i.e if the pattern were to be applied, the following example would only return the asp:checkbox control with ID = checkbox_ID?

```
<asp:Checkbox ID="checkbox_ID" CssClass="checkbox_CSS" runat="server" />
<asp:Checkbox ID="checkbox_ID2" runat="server" />
```

The main goal is to be able to find all controls with a predefined CssClass element and change them all to use another class of my choosing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could search for this:

```
(<asp:[^>]+CssClass=")checkbox_CSS("[^>]+>)
```

And replace with this (where "new_class" is the new value for the `CssClass` attribute):

```
$1new_class$2
```

([Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3Casp%3A%5B%5E%3E%5D%2BCssClass%3D%22)checkbox_CSS(%22%5B%5E%3E%5D%2B%3E)&i=%3Casp%3ACheckbox%20ID%3D%22checkbox_ID%22%20CssClass%3D%22checkbox_CSS%22%20runat%3D%22server%22%20%2F%3E%0D%0A%3Casp%3ACheckbox%20ID%3D%22checkbox_ID2%22%20runat%3D%22server%22%20%2F%3E&r=%241new_class%242))

Comment: Thank you for your response! The pattern was close to exactly what I was looking for. How would I be able to manipulate it to only select CssClass="checkbox_CSS" when the search is run? Right now it is highlighting the entire row of text.

Comment: If you only want to match that part of the string, you can just change the first group to a look-behind and the last group to a look ahead, like this: (?<=<asp:[^>]+CssClass=")checkbox_CSS(?="[^>]+>)

Comment: However, if you do that, you want to just replace with the new class name without the $1 and $2

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

```
<[^>]*CssClass[^>]*>
```

See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nK3cP7/1)